# I have been trying to write a program using a python and mysql connection to open a particular website based on the users input

Tags: python, mysql

When I try to run my code for opening a website based on the user's input it does not work.

I tried using an IF condition to open a website based on whether the user's input fulfills the condition.

The source code is pasted below :-

```
import mysql.connector
import webbrowser
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="pass")
mycon=mydb.cursor()
mycon.execute('create database projects')
mycon.execute('use projects')
mycon.execute('create table products(ID varchar(3),Name varchar(20),Type varchar(20))')
s='insert into products(ID,Name,Type)VALUES(%s,%s,%s)'
v=[('A01','EG1','ABC'),('A02','EG2','DEF'),('A03','EG3','GHI')]
mycon.executemany(s,v)
a=str(input("enter the product id"))
if a=="A01":
    webbrowser.open("https://duckduckgo.com/")
```

This is the output :-

`enter the product id A01`

After the input of the id nothing happens. The strange thing is this only happens if I use the IF condition to try and open a website based on the input. How do I fix this ?

Comment: Your code is almost definitely getting to `webbrowser.open()` line, but is doing nothing. Are you certain there is no error being thrown that you are just overlooking?